# Need to retain dynamically created option in combo box using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a codeset that dynamically creates an "option" in a select box. But, since we're using Knockout, when I go to SELECT that newly created option, and click on it, it gets removed, e.g. DISAPPEARS! Poof!!!!

So, here's the create script:

```
    function createNewGroup()
    {

        var htmlSelect = document.getElementById('groups');
        var optionValue = document.getElementById('newgroupname');

        if (optionValue.value === '')
        {
            alert('Please enter group name.');
            optionValue.focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (isOptionAlreadyExist(htmlSelect, optionValue.value))
        {
            optionValue.value = "";
            alert('Group name already exists.\n\nPlease try again.');
            optionValue.focus();
            return false;
        }

        var selectBoxOption = document.createElement("option");
        selectBoxOption.value = optionValue.value;
        selectBoxOption.text = optionValue.value;
        htmlSelect.add(selectBoxOption, null);

        optionValue.value = "";
        alert("New group has been added successfully.");
        optionValue.focus();
        return true;

    };
```

Since this is a KNOCKOUT observable, how to keep it in the box when I select it, moreover, how do I send that new value back to JSON object. Here's an example of that:

{"groups":[

```
    {
        "groupname" : "Administrator",
        "attr" : {  "id" : "li.attr.node_1",
                    "href" : "#", 
                    "data-bind" : "click: grpMgmt('Administrator');" }
    },
    {
        "groupname" : "Guest",
        "attr" : {  "id" : "li.attr.node_2",
                    "href" : "#", 
                    "data-bind" : "click: grpMgmt('Guest');"  }
    }
]
```

}

Hence, the admin user can create a new user so it can look like this:

{"groups":[

```
    {
        "groupname" : "Administrator",
        "attr" : {  "id" : "li.attr.node_1",
                    "href" : "#", 
                    "data-bind" : "click: grpMgmt('Administrator');" }
    },
    {
        "groupname" : "Guest",
        "attr" : {  "id" : "li.attr.node_2",
                    "href" : "#", 
                    "data-bind" : "click: grpMgmt('Guest');"  }
    }
],
```

"users":[

```
    {
        "groupname" : "Joes Users",
        "attr" : {  "id" : "li.attr.node_1",
                    "href" : "#", 
                    "data-bind" : "click: grpMgmt('Joe');" }
    }
]
```

}

OK, I'll stop writing for now... thanks...

Comment: Where's the knockout?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using knockout (which I can't actually see) all you need to do is bind your select box to an observable array and when you need to add a new item just push it onto the array and knockout will add it to the list for you.

Knockout should essentially replace that script you've included with a lot less, much more simplistic code.

Comment: OK, yeah, you're right... now, I'm pretty green when it comes to KO.  Here's my Bound Select box:                                              

<div id="groupsRoles" class="groupsroles">
                                                <label><strong>Roles/Groups:</strong>&nbsp;</label>  
                                                <select id="groups" data-bind="options: groups, value: selectedGroup, change: grpMgmt(this.value), enable: !haveChanged()"></select>
                                            </div>